# How to proxy all inherited methods in python

Tags: python, proxy

I want to proxy all inherited methods of a class. I need to do this because I want to add some information before forward the method call. I've something like:

```py
class Father():
    def fatherMethodOne(self):
        print("This is father method one")
    
    def fatherMethodTwo(self):
        print("This is father method two")

class Child(Father):
    
    ALLOWED_OPTIONS = ["test"]
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._options = {
            "test": True
        }
```

Notice that I've a `_options` in the `Child` class, I want to perform some operations using the `_options` before call any inherent method from `Father`.

I've tried for example the following code:

```py
class Father():
    def fatherMethodOne(self):
        print("This is father method one")
    
    def fatherMethodTwo(self):
        print("This is father method two")

class Child(Father):
    
    ALLOWED_OPTIONS = ["test"]
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._options = {
            "test": True
        }
    
    def __getattribute__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        for key in self._options.keys():
            if key not in Child.ALLOWED_OPTIONS:
                raise KeyError("Key not allowed")
        return super().__getattribute__(__name)
    
    
print(Child().fatherMethodOne())
```

But I get the following error (I've omitted filepath):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 105, in <module>
    print(Child().fatherMethodOne())
  File "filepath", line 99, in __getattribute__
    for key in self._options.keys():
  File "filepath", line 99, in __getattribute__
    for key in self._options.keys():
  File "filepath", line 99, in __getattribute__
    for key in self._options.keys():
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I can't override every method from `Father` because in the real case there is a lot of functions to override. So this is why I want to do it in a way where I don't need to override every single function from father.

So, there is a way to do that?

Comment: `self._options` is triggering `.__getattribute__()` recursively. It should be `super().__getattribute__('_options')`.

Comment: Why are there so many methods in the class? It sounds like it's doing too much and should be split up.

Comment: @ndc85430 That class might not be OP's.

Comment: `__getattribute__` is supposed to raise `AttributeError`, not `KeyError`.